# ¿Cómo quitar espacios en sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy realizando una consulta donde estoy concatenando con la función `CONCAT` una letra, pero a la hora de ver los resultados, me sale con unos espacios anteriores a la cadena de texto que tiene, lo trate de realizar las siguientes formas:

```
SELECT Sucursal, Nombre, Str_Company, Str_Sucursal, Estatus, RTRIM(LTRIM(CONCAT(AlmacenPrincipal, 'H'))) FROM #TempSucursal212IBCO

SELECT Sucursal, Nombre, Str_Company, Str_Sucursal, Estatus, TRIM(CONCAT(AlmacenPrincipal, 'H')) FROM #TempSucursal212IBCO
```

Pero sigo con el mismo resultado: [image: texto con espacios]

¿Alguien me podría apoyar diciendome que estoy realizando mal?, se los agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero debes quitar los espacios con RTRIM Y LTRIM, luego concatenar, intenta realizarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT Sucursal, Nombre, Str_Company, 
Str_Sucursal, Estatus,
CONCAT(RTRIM(LTRIM(AlmacenPrincipal)), 'H')
FROM #TempSucursal212IBCO
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta Erik, me ayudó bastante.